# 1D Motion homework

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, velocity, speed

> A helicopter is ascending vertically with a speed of 4.00 m/s. At a height of 125 m above the Earth, a package is dropped from a window. How much time does it take for the package to reach the ground? [Hint: The package's initial speed equals the helicopter's.]

So using the displacement formula $x=x_0 + v_0t + (1/2)at^2$, I did $-4.9t^2 - 4t + 125 =0$ at first, because the package was travelling downwards and so its initial velocity would be negative. However, instead, solving 
$-4.9t^2 +​4t + 125 =0$ returned the correct answer (I just fit in the equation using the hint). But I don't understand why then the initial velocity of the falling package would be $4.00m/s$, not a negative value.

Comment: Isn't the package initially moving upward relative to the ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo, the equation you want to solve is $-4.9t^2+4t+125=0$.

Since the initial velocity and acceleration have an opposite direction, they must have different sign

Answer (score 0):

As you have put the acceleration, which acts downwards, as negative. This means up is positive. The initial velocity of the package is 4m/s upwards (as the helicopter was ascending vertically) so it will be positive.